# Reading floats from file with python

Tags: python, floating-point

My input file has the form:

```
5.0, 1000.0, 100000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408, 
1.053E-09, 1.839E-09, 1.632E-10, 1.959E-12, 4.109, 3.683, 3.586, 3.650
```

where every number is essentially in a line.

What I want to do is read all the floats, and then append only columns 7 through 10 to an array.

Here's what I've written:

```
T=[]
with open("test.txt", "r") as file1:
    for line in file1.readlines():
        f_list = [float(i) for i in line.split(",")]
        T.append(float(f_list[7]))
        T.append(float(f_list[8]))
        T.append(float(f_list[9]))
        T.append(float(f_list[10]))
```

When I run the above I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I think there's something wrong with the `float(i)` part, but I can't find a way around it.

I've seen people having similar problems here, but none of the fixes I've tried so far have helped. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere in there you have something that isn't a float as text. Examine the file.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's probably the trailing space at his first line that is causing the error. That will cause a empty string to be produce. And when that is passed to `float()`, it fails.

Comment: I don't get it. Every float is a line, but you have columns? Did you mean rows, or are there more than one float on each line after all?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What I meant was that the way it appears on this site could confuse someone as to believe that I have written 2 line, when I have written one.

Comment: Ah, OK, got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the problem is that your **first line ends with a comma**:

```
5.0, 1000.0, 100000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408,
1.053E-09, 1.839E-09, 1.632E-10, 1.959E-12, 4.109, 3.683, 3.586, 3.650
```

As a result, you want to process a string that **only contains spaces** (like `' '`). And `float(' ')` fails since it is not a number (it actually reports this):

```
>>> float(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
>>> float('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

But a space simply is invisible when printed.

You can solve it by adding a **filter statement** to the list comprehension:

```
T = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as file1:
    for line in file1.readlines():
        f_list = [float(i) for i in line.split(",") if i.strip()]
        T += f_list[7:11]
```

Furthermore this will **not** work since **none of the lines has 7-11** floats. So you will never add these floats anyway.

You can however use the following code:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file1:
    f_list = [float(i) for line in file1 for i in line.split(',') if i.strip()]
    T = f_list[7:11]
```

This will result in `T` being equal to:

```
>>> T
[1.053e-09, 1.839e-09, 1.632e-10, 1.959e-12]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you split `line`, the resulting list most likely contains whitespace. This would cause `float()` to fail. You need to sanitize your split list first by testing if an element is actually a valid float number. eg:

```
>>> def is_float(n):
    try:
        float(n)
        return True
    except:
        return False


>>> 
>>> line = '5.0, 1000.0, 100000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408,'
>>> lst = [float(n) for n in line.split(',') if is_float(n)]
>>> lst
[5.0, 1000.0, 100000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408]
>>>
```