# Python import text file values as float

Tags: python, arrays

I haven't found a solution so far and I tried so many things. Hope some of you guys can help me. I am using Python.

I have a .txt file with values like:     `9,5,7,6,4`

And I want to read this file as an array with float values, so it should look like:

```
array([9.0, 5.0, 7.0, 6.0, 4.0], dtype=float32)
```

The only thing I found so far is looks like:

```
array(['9,5,7,6,4),dtype='<U9'])
```

and is a string and not a float.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading floats from file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975599/reading-floats-from-file-with-python)

Comment: read it as text using `open()`, `read()`; split in with `split(",")` and you get list `["9", "5" , "7", "6", "4"]` - and use `for`-loop with `float()` to convert every element on list to float value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it as text

```
text = open(filename).read()  # "9,5,7,6,4"
```

split to list of strings

```
data = text.split(',')  # ["9", "5" , "7", "6", "4"]
```

convert every string to float

```
values = [float(x) for x in data]  # [9.0, 5.0, 7.0, 6.0, 4.0]
```

---

Example code

```
#text = open(filename).read()
text = '9,5,7,6,4'

data = text.split(',')
values = [float(x) for x in data]

print(values)
# [9.0, 5.0, 7.0, 6.0, 4.0]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `array()` then probably you use `numpy` so you should see [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) which should do what you want - you have to only use `delimiter=','`